# Scroll pyqt6 QListView to show selected item when set with Python Code

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I checked out some postings about this but for some reason or other none have worked for me.

I want to be able to set a selected item within a pyqt6 QListView with python and have the list automatically scroll the list to ensure the selected item is visible.  The setting of the selection works for me but I'm unable to get the list to scroll.

**Setting:** serviceTypeList.setCurrentIndex(serviceTypeModel.index(foundIdx,0)  this works....

**Scrolling:** serviceTypeList.scrollTo(serviceTypeList.currentIndex(), serviceTypeList.ScrollHint.EnsureVisible)  this does not work....

I also tried by adding the following right after I declared the ListView

serviceTypeList.ScrollHint = QAbstractItemView.ScrollHint.EnsureVisible  does not work....

I'm new to pyqt6 so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.... setting the currentIndex with a QListWidget worked without issue but I decided to use a QListView to be able to set the background for selected item.

any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but we cannot work with just a few snippets taken out of context, please provide a valid [mre] (and ensure that you're properly [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...... when I went about supplying a shorter bit code I discovered that setting current Index works, so it was something in my code that was preventing scrolling.  What ended up solving my issue was simply setting a fixed height for the list.